# paper specifications and procurement -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning

Example with a context:

> Founded in 1807, John Wiley & Sons, Inc. has been a valued source of knowledge and understanding for more than 200 years, helping people around the world meet their needs and fulfill their aspirations. Our company is built on a foundation of principles that include responsibility to the communities we serve and where we live and work. In 2008, we launched a Corporate Citizenship Initiative, a global effort to address the environmental, social, economic, and ethical challenges we face in our business. Among the issues we are addressing are carbon impact, **paper specifications and procurement**, ethical conduct within our business and among our vendors, and community and charitable support. For more information, please visit our website: www.wiley.com/go/citizenship.

What does *paper specifications and procurement* really mean?

Comment: It means what kind of paper you buy and who you buy it from--matters which can have a significant impact on the environment when a book publisher is the buyer. For instance, check out [this article](http://www.greeningtheblue.org/case-study/world-bank-chasing-paper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paper specifications means qualities of the paper: thickness, new or recycled, strength, moisture resistance, etc.

Procurement means purchasing, but for a business.

His point is they want to responsibly source paper within the company. A good paper supplier would have forests sustain-ably replanted and managed. A poor paper supplier may clear cut rain forests, and dump waste chemicals into the adjacent river. It's important to Wiley to ensure they're buying paper from companies in the first category.